# Getting information from FASTA annots in R

Tags: r, sequence, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a large FASTA file that I need to analyse for a class.

I found help in the question asked here [How to search and isolate attributes of FASTA formatted text in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518485/how-to-search-and-isolate-attributes-of-fasta-formatted-text-in-r). However, I am still having trouble manipulating the data.
using the function `getAnnots()`, I get a list of the "annots" in the following format:

```
>annots
[[i]]
[1] ">SourceAccessionCode | StrainName | type / subtupe | OtherInfo | "
```

I want to change this list format into a data frame where each element of the list, each on a separate row, is split into four columns (each containing the information in the example above).

I tried different combinations of the `strsplit()` function with `sapply()` and `for` loops, but to no avail.
even using the `strsplit()` on it's own is giving unsatisfactory results

> strsplit(GISAnnots[[i]], split = " | ")
>       [[i]]
>        [1] ">sourceAccessionCode"       "|"                    "StrainName" "|"
>        [5] "Type"                    "/"                    "Subtype"                 "|"
>        [9] "MoreInfo"                "|"

And using `for` loops gives the following results

```
> info <- for (i in 1:length(GISAnnots))
+   strsplit(GISAnnots[[i]], split = " | ")
> info
NULL
```

I apologise I do not have a concrete example because I can not think of an example to show the work, and I can't use my own data as an example due to copyright restraints.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Without looking at your data it would be very hard to help. Could you somewhat change your data and just show the format of them?

Comment: @nicola, my data is a result of a standard `read.fasta()` function, the example used in the question I linked is a good example, however my "annots" attribute follows the format I mentioned above.

Comment: How did you use `strsplit` and why it didn't work?

Comment: I used it in several combinations with for loops and I keep getting errors I don't understand (I'm rather new to R...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some data

```
elt = ">SourceAccessionCode | StrainName | type / subtupe | OtherInfo | "
lst = list(elt, elt))
```

Probably the first problem is that this is a list, but you'd like it to be unlisted. A neat trick for not too large data is to pretend that the text is input to `read.delim()` or similar

```
> read.delim(text=unlist(lst), sep="|", header=FALSE, strip.white=TRUE)
                    V1         V2             V3        V4 V5
1 >SourceAccessionCode StrainName type / subtupe OtherInfo NA
2 >SourceAccessionCode StrainName type / subtupe OtherInfo NA
```

maybe adding `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. The [Biostrings](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html) package also has `readDNAStringSet()` for working with fasta files, where the names of the fasta sequences would be retrieved with `names(readDNAStringSet('your.fasta'))`

Comment: Actually my data set is quite large (about 9000 sequences) and I'm working with amino acid sequences, not DNA...

Comment: @ASH.K `names(readAAStringSet("your.fasta"))`; 9000 sequences is fine for the `read.delim()` solution -- did you try it?

Comment: I just tried the `read.delim()` solution, it worked PERFECTLY! thank you for your help...